# Generic function that takes an object and a member name as parameters?

Tags: c#, function, class, object, generics

Is there a way to create a generic function that can take an object as a parameter and also one of it's members. So that I could do something like this:

```
Sort(List<inventory>, inventoryClass.count);

//Do something to display the inventory items sorted by their count member

Sort(List<inventory>, inventoryClass.price);

//Do something to display the inventory items sorted by price.
```

Then later on even use it on lists of different objects and different members.

How would this function look? How could I use a variable to decide which member I am looking at to sort?

Answer (score 3):

One way to build that is to have the second parameter be a selector function - a `Func<inventory,object>` that receives the object in question and returns the property to sort by.

```
List<inventory> Sort(List<inventory> list, 
                     Func<inventory, object> orderBySelector)
{
    return list.OrderBy(orderBySelector).ToList();
}
```

and then you'd call it by passing an anonymous function, usually a lamba expression:

```
var listSortedByPrice = Sort(originalList, item => item.price);
var listSortedByCount = Sort(originalList, item => item.count);
```

Of course, with the minimal amount of work that the `Sort` function does, you'd be better off just using LINQ's `OrderBy` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Func<TItem, TField>`. In `Sort` you can use it like this:

```
Sort<TItem, TField>(List<TItem> list, Func<TItem, TField> func)
{
    var field = func(list[0]);
}
```

and you call Sort like this:

```
Sort(yourList, item => item .count);
```